# What is "Shtopp Zman"?

Tags: zemanim, language, mikvah-ritual-bath

A prerecorded english language message of a local *mikvah* informs that the *mikvah* is open from an hour before *Shtopp Zman* (approximate phonetic spelling, as I do not know this phrase). The recording can be heard by calling +44(0)20-8806-3880.

What and when is that? Why is it called like that when such a phrase is not used on *luchos* (Jewish law calendars)?

Comment: שטופּ-שעה is rush hour, so perhaps also שטופּ-זמן?

Comment: Approximately what regional dialect of what language is this potentially?

Comment: @DoubleAA Could be anything; English, Hungarian or Litvish Yiddish, Any pronounciation of Hebrew...

Comment: Shtub is Shtible is Shtiblech....

Comment: @kouty Eh, so it translates to "house" or "room" or "wife", but what does it *mean*?

Comment: @Adám Beth hamidrash of Chassidim.

Comment: Is it a Mikve of Shul or a mikveh for Taharat Hamishpacha?

Comment: @kouty Taharah.

Comment: Shtopp zeman need to be the zman of tevila of evening. (The minhag is because of Srach Bita, to follow zman tevila of niddah.). S = Stars O = out, or somewath else.

Comment: Any chance you can get a recording online?

Comment: Are you sure it is saying "Shtopp" and not "shtot"? ... If so "shtot zman" would translate as "city zman" -- Shtot is yiddish for city. This in general refers to the time that a particular city accepts that night time has begun (for all relevant halachos.) So this would obviously vary from city to city. What is acceptable in England?

Comment: @Yehoshua No, I'm not sure. It may be the somewhat unfamiliar British accent.

Answer (score 2):

It's "shtot zman" - "the city time (for tzeis hakochavim)".

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Thanks for the answer. Consider editing it to clarify why the city time would refer particularly to tzeis hakochavim, and why they would announce this.

Comment: I think it is used to indicate that this is the (Beis din of the) city's (i.e. the UOHC) official time for motzei shabbos, as opposed to the Rabbeinu Tam time chassidim tend to follow.

Answer (score 1):

This Mikva is located in Stoke Newington London. The message is saying that the Mikva opens 1 hour before the Stoke Zeman.

Comment: Except it isn't in Stoke Newington, it's in Cazenove! Also, nobody calls Stoke Newington "Stoke", and the Jews refer to the entire area as Stamford Hill, even surrounding areas like South Tottenham. However, this Mikvah happens to be located right off the actual Stamford Hill (part of the A10 road), so using the name of Stoke (Newington) doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: http://locviuk.com/loc/stamford-hill-district-ladies-mikvah-3501655

Comment: [Stoke Newington](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Stoke+Newington,+London) vs. [mikvah location](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Stamford+Hill+%26+District+Ladies+Mikvah).

Comment: @Adám: It is less than a mile away. So I still think my answer makes sense.